# django problem iterating over SelectMultiple/CheckboxSelectMultiple in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I'm having a real hard time with this problem because I found the answer but it doesn't work. I have a Django app with a form with a SelectMultiple/CheckboxSelectMultiple field...

### My Aim

I need to iterate in the template over the options of my "labels" field.
Printing `{{ form.labels }}` in the template works fine (that is, that object gets there OK).

### My Problem

All over the web I found the same way to do this - and I tried all variations I could think of. For exampl see @Jarret Hardie 's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733880/iterate-over-choices-in-checkboxselectmultiple/734025#734025).

### My Code

models.py

```
class myModle(models.Model):
  labels = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
  class Meta:
    db_table = u'myTable'
```

forms.py

```
class MYMODELForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = myModel
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MYMODELForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    labelList = set()
    #now I'm filling the set with strings (label names)
    #one of the two following line:
    self.fields['labels'] = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(choices=[(x,x) for x in labelList]))
    self.fields['labels'] = forms.CharField(required=False,widget=forms.SelectMultiple(choices=[(x,x) for x in labelList]))
```

myTemplate.html

```
<table>
    <tr>
         <td>
            <!-- All variations of... -->
            {% for choice_id, choice_label in form.labels.field.items %} 
            {{ choice_id }} = {{ choice_label }} <br/>
            {% endfor %} 
         </td>
     </tr>
 </table>
```

myStyle.css

```
Nothing interesting her...
```

views.py

```
Nothing interesting her...
```

### So...

Why oh why is this not working???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `items` instead of `choices`.

Current:

`{% for choice_id, choice_label in form.labels.field.items %}`

Should be:

`{% for choice_id, choice_label in form.labels.field.choices %}`

since you've put the choices on the widget, those choices override the field's choices, so iterate over the widget choices:

`{% for choice_id, choice_label in form.labels.field.widget.choices %}`

Comment: It's not working (I actually started with this). The HTML page doesn't show anything in this part - that's the big problem.

Comment: Took another look at the code. You've set the choices on the widget, not the field (widget choices override field choices upon render). So try iterating over `form.labels.field.widget.choices`.

Comment: And how to check if option is checked?

Comment: Get it from the field value.